# Почему при нажатии на элемент списка выделяется весь ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Вылезла странная проблема. На андроид 2.3 при нажатии на один элемент списка выделяется весь ListView тем же цветом, что и один элемент списка.
Я использую кастомный selector.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/color_press" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/color_press" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/color_press" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/color_press" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/color_press" />
</selector>
```

ListView в xml. Вроде бы ничего плохого не должно быть.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:divider="#B7B7B7"
              android:dividerHeight="1px"
              android:listSelector="@drawable/list_view_selector"
            />
```

Кто нибудь видел такое?

Comment: android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
может поможет)

Comment: @katso нет, не помогло.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем я забил на это. Решение не нашлось. Я просто игнорирую андроид 2.3 и младше.
Там есть radiobutton, так что не существенно.

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся с этой же проблемой на **Android 2.0**.

Ответ нашел в интернете.
Суть в том, что я в `android:listSelector=` указывал сразу цвет `("@color/отсылка на цвет")`, а нужно было так:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/item"
```

В папке **res/drawable** файл **item.xml**:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/fe" /> <!-- ваш цвет -->
</shape>
```

Comment: а внутри item.xml -shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/fe" - ваш цвет.